# FormatException Uint8List convert to string with dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to convert a Uint8List to a string using Dart (in a Flutter project).
I am using the Flutter Android USB Serial plugin ( https://github.com/altera2015/usbserial)

The data are coming from a usb device and are returned from the library as a Stream.

If outputed as a string, it looks like:

[255,0,0,0,255....]

When I try:

```
String newTag = ascii.decode(asyncSnapshot.data);
```

I get the error :

```
FormatException:Invalid value in input: 255
```

I don't know how to solve this issue, my result should be :

```
"352206000079439"
```

Comment: Why do you need to store arbitrary bytes as a `String`?

Comment: I am using data coming from a usb device connected to the phone (serial). This device sends data to my flutter application. The type of the data is Uint8List. I need to retrieve the value.

Comment: That doesn't explain why you need it as a `String` instead of keeping it as a `Uint8List`.

Comment: The string is referenced in a database. Those values come from an electronic tag that I read using a RFID reader. The reader reads the tag, sends the value. It uses this value to query a database.

Comment: Dart `String`s are expected to store valid UTF-16.  Trying to store arbitrary data as a `String` is asking for trouble.  If you need a `String` to use as a key into the database, then you will need to do something else, such as *encoding* your data to a `String`(e.g. base64) and using the encoded form instead.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one;

```
List<int> list = 'someData'.codeUnits;
Uint8List bytes = Uint8List.fromList(list);
String string = String.fromCharCodes(bytes);
```

Comment: I have tested your code and i get a string: "ŸŸŸŸŸŸŸŸ". But what i should get is "352206000079439"

Answer (score 0):

If data has compressed as a blob type.

```
Uint8List bytes = Uint8List.fromList(tcp_socket_blob_data);
var inflated = zlib.decode(bytes);
var data = utf8.decode(inflated);
```

More: [flutter/dart: How to decompress/inflate zlib binary string in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58414164/flutter-dart-how-to-decompress-inflate-zlib-binary-string-in-flutter)